# Redirect in subfolder based on url

Tags: .htaccess, dns, apache2

I plan to run multiple sites on that server.

I looked arround a bit but only found rather cryptic stuff i can't work with.

So basically all projects reside in their subfolder in /var/www/. Multiple sites go with multiple domains, so what I want to accomplish is this:

http://example.com goes to my xx.xx.xx (serverip) and loads the site in /var/www/example/publicdir/index.php

http://something.else maps to /var/www/something/publicdir/index.php

Is it something that needs to be done in the apache on the server via virtualhosts? I'm completely clueless

Oh yeah I have an extra condition, I dont want 301 Redirects

I hope you can get through my babbling, my head feels like jelly since I'm trying to get it done for a few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `VirtualHost` config. You don't need any mod_rewrite stuff. You can setup multiple domains in same Apache config with one `VirtualHost` section for each domain.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is to have different Document root for different domains. The example here will help you http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html#xtra-conf

Comment: i found that one already, but without any real knowledge about .htaccess this is near to complete jibberish for me